# IF Function, Excel - How do I set a value to True if column A1:A10 is set to "Pass"?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm trying to set a cell (J2) to say `Completed` if cells G2:G41 *all* have a value of `"Pass"` else display `Bugs` if any of those cells have `"Fail"` in them.

The formula I've got at the moment is:

```
=IF(G2:G41="Pass", "Completed", "Bugs")
```

But it keeps saying `Completed` when cell G41 is set to `"Fail"`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this...

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G2:G41,"Pass")=ROWS(G2:G41),"Completed","Bugs")
```

**Edit:**
If the range G2:G41 may contains blanks and you only want to count if all the filled cells in this range have "Pass" in them, you may try something like this...

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G2:G41,"Pass")=COUNTA(G2:G41),"Completed","Bugs")
```

So the edited formula will ignore the blank cells in the range G2:G41.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not entering an ARRAY function, excel evaluates only the value of the first cell, G2.

Another approach:

```
=IF(NOT(SUM(--(G1:G41<>"pass"))),"Completed", "Bugs")
```

And press ctrl+shift+enter to complete formula.